# All the punctuation features across languages

Tags: cross-linguistic, punctuation

Wondering what features of language or writing that languages across the world transcribe into so-called "punctuation".

To clarify what I mean, I don't mean a list of every punctuation character in every language (though that would be neat). I instead mean this. In language **generally**, there are certain things we can consider *punctuation*:

- the colon `:` I just used (start of a list or hmm, I'm not sure exactly what this means at a deeper level)
- the space (word separator)
- `.` (end of sentence)
- `,` (list item separator)
- `"` (quotation)
- `'` (compound word joiner)
- `?` (question)
- `!` (exclamation)
- `()` (sidenote)
- `$` (money sign, different in each culture)
- `@` (fairly new, digital address perhaps)
- `#` (number marker)
- `&` (archaic "and" sign)
- `[]` (footnote or citation perhaps)

That's about all I can think of *in English*. But I can think of potential other ones that might use a symbol (plus, markdown gives us some options too):

- `-` (vertical list item marker)
- `|` (table column)
- italics for emphasis
- bold for a lot of emphasis

Maybe even some others:

- something for a *joking* phrase
- something for a code block
- ...

Basically I'm wondering what other languages do for punctuation here. Not necessarily the symbols they use, but the things they punctuate.

Comment: Good question.  Maybe it's a function of orthography and *domain*, not language per se, and there is a difference between what is theoretically prescribed or possible and what is widely used and understood.  For example, ¶ and §.

Comment: To just get all punctuation, you can look at the Unicode blocks.  In Python there is also a function like *isalpha()*, and some libraries, and then you can loop over the entire set of chars.

Comment: As for other languages, some that comes to mind is the function of em dash in Russian to mark the null copula, and the ¡ and ¿ in Spanish to give questions proper intonation.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, there are superscripts/subscripts as well, and I know tibetan has some extra markers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tibetan_alphabet#Modifiers, and sanskrit has one for rhythm.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer The Python standard library module `unicodedata` is even more useful here; it lets you, in effect, interactively explore the Unicode database. There's no `ispunct` method on strings, but there is `unicodedata.category(s).startswith('P')`. [Here's an online example I whipped up.](https://repl.it/repls/TomatoUnwittingApplicationpackage) Run it, type in characters, and it'll tell you which category each character is. The ones starting with "P" are punctuation.

Comment: Note that `@` existed for about half a millennium before being used in email. It's called the "at sign" because of its use in trade: "10 widgets @ £1" means "10 widgets at 1 pound each", so the total price is £10. Its modern use comes down to the fact that it was already on computer keyboards, and was one of the few symbols that didn't already have a more obvious use in Arpanet email processing, so it was drafted into use as the delimiter between user and host/route.

Comment: Also, `&` is hardly archaic in English.